# Send SMS secretly (I don't want it to appear in my outbox)

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm making a security app that sends a SMS with the next code:

```
public static void SendSMS(String message, String number) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
}
```

It works perfectly but my question is:
Is there any way to delete (programmatically) from my outbox the SMS my app sends? I don't want other users to be able to see it if they check the outbox of my user.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can delete sms with specific number but no way to get only outbox msg

Comment: send the message and delete if from the outbox

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that maybe the user won't be able to delete it, so I have to provide a service to hide/delete it programmatically as I said. @NiravRanpara

Comment: Since you're apparently not writing the messages to the sent box yourself, this means that you're running under Android 4.4+, and that your app is not the default SMS app. Since Android 4.4, only the default SMS app has standard write access to the Provider, which means you can't really delete messages unless your app is the default. There might be another option, though, depending on who's supposed to receive the messages, and how.

Comment: I'm running above Android 4.4 @MikeM. Actually I'm running my app in Android 5.1.1  If you know how to solve it please help! thanks :)

Comment: Data SMS, also know as port-addressed, or binary SMS, are not saved by the Provider. If your intended recipients can handle data SMS, then you can send those without them showing in any other app.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but try below function

[content //sms](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.html)

```
public void deletesms(Context context, String number) {
    try {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/outbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
                        "date", "body" }, "read=0", null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);
                String date = c.getString(3);


                if (address.equals(number)) {

                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), "date=?",
                            new String[] { c.getString(4) });
                    Log.e("log", "Delete ");
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log", e.toString());
    }
    }
```

permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"> </ uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"> </ uses-permission>
```

Comment: This is not working, sms still visible in the sms conversation.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public void deleteSMS(Context context, String message, String number) {
try {
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/outbox");
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
            uriSms,
            new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
                    "date", "body" }, "read=0", null, null);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            long id = c.getLong(0);
            long threadId = c.getLong(1);
            String address = c.getString(2);
            String body = c.getString(5);
            String date = c.getString(3);
            Log.e("log>>>",
                    "0>" + c.getString(0) + "1>" + c.getString(1)
                            + "2>" + c.getString(2) + "<-1>"
                            + c.getString(3) + "4>" + c.getString(4)
                            + "5>" + c.getString(5));
            Log.e("log>>>", "date" + c.getString(0));

            if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                context.getContentResolver().delete(
                        Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), "date=?",
                        new String[] { c.getString(4) });
                Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success.........");
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log>>>", e.toString());
}}
```

Cheers !!

Comment: This is not working, sms still visible in the sms conversation.

Comment: Check the parameters accurately !!